# Error APPX1204: Failed to sign UWP Project

Tags: uwp, certificate, win-universal-app, signing

I have a PC with VS 16.4.5. I've been always able to create and publish succesfully UWP projects, but since last week, I have no idea what happened I receive this error every time I try to build any UWP project (even dummy ones).

```
1>------ Build started: Project: App1, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
1>  App1 -> C:\Users\my_user\source\repos\App1\App1\bin\x86\Debug\App1.exe
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(4573,5): error APPX1204: Failed to sign 'C:\Users\my_user\source\repos\App1\App1\bin\x86\Debug\App1_1.0.4.0_x86_Debug.msix'.
```

I've been so desperate that I formated my PC this morning, installed everything again, Was able to generate a package, but then I don't know if it's because I installed some Xamarin SDKs and Android simulator, started to fail again signing the package. I also installed a certificate in to the Trusted Authority Roots, but I have no clue what is happening.

If I create a new UWP project, create a Test certificate for it, fails miserably.

I tried to generate a package with SignTool.exe in:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\signtool.exe`

but it doesn't matter what parameters i add, it doesn't yield any response or error on the command line

Thanks

Comment: As the link @laxxifer given shows, some customers said if they remove KB4535996  and reboot, the issue will be fixed. Could you please try this?

Comment: Yeah, show it. I'll do that or wait for an update from Windows. Just wondering how no one at Microsoft had this problem before as signing a package is a day to day thing for UWP developers. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/934967/uwp-error-failed-to-sign.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is under triaged by Microsoft.

At this link you can see the progress.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/934749/failed-to-sign-appx.html

Answer (score 1):

> Windows 10 update KB4540673 of 10/03/2020 should solve the problem.

Already tested on Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.4.6)

Comment: Will wait until they provide an update on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/934967/uwp-error-failed-to-sign.html but thanks!