# UWP project failed on GitHub Actions because certificate is invalid APPX0107

Tags: uwp, msbuild, github-actions, building-github-actions

I have a project in GitHub that have UWP project in [here](https://github.com/soroshsabz/PCLAppConfig).

I want to setup GitHub Actions for this project with [this main.yml configuration](https://github.com/soroshsabz/PCLAppConfig/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml)

When GitHub Actions want to build my solution with below commands

```
- name: Library build

  run: |

    cd src

    nuget restore

    msbuild PCLAppConfig.sln /verbosity:normal /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release
```

I see failed error with below error in UWP building

```
2020-03-23T13:07:20.1871936Z "D:\a\PCLAppConfig\PCLAppConfig\src\PCLAppConfig.sln" (Rebuild target) (1) ->
2020-03-23T13:07:20.1872322Z "D:\a\PCLAppConfig\PCLAppConfig\src\DemoApp\DemoApp.UWP\DemoApp.UWP.csproj" (Rebuild target) (10) ->
2020-03-23T13:07:20.1872524Z (_GenerateCurrentProjectAppxManifest target) -> 
2020-03-23T13:07:20.1872807Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2650,5): warning APPX0107: The certificate specified is not valid for signing. For more information about valid certificates, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478. [D:\a\PCLAppConfig\PCLAppConfig\src\DemoApp\DemoApp.UWP\DemoApp.UWP.csproj]
2020-03-23T13:07:20.1873172Z 
2020-03-23T13:07:20.1873447Z 
2020-03-23T13:07:20.1873657Z "D:\a\PCLAppConfig\PCLAppConfig\src\PCLAppConfig.sln" (Rebuild target) (1) ->
2020-03-23T13:07:20.1873802Z "D:\a\PCLAppConfig\PCLAppConfig\src\DemoApp\DemoApp.UWP\DemoApp.UWP.csproj" (Rebuild target) (10) ->
2020-03-23T13:07:20.1873935Z (_GenerateAppxPackageFile target) -> 
2020-03-23T13:07:20.1874153Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3402,5): error APPX0107: The certificate specified is not valid for signing. For more information about valid certificates, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478. [D:\a\PCLAppConfig\PCLAppConfig\src\DemoApp\DemoApp.UWP\DemoApp.UWP.csproj]
2020-03-23T13:07:20.1874919Z 
2020-03-23T13:07:20.1875022Z     4 Warning(s)
2020-03-23T13:07:20.1875125Z     1 Error(s)
2020-03-23T13:07:20.1875697Z 
2020-03-23T13:07:20.1875988Z Time Elapsed 00:03:28.50
2020-03-23T13:07:20.6575030Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

the note is if I run `msbuild PCLAppConfig.sln /verbosity:normal /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release` in local computer, build is successfully and does not have any error, and I can run UWP app locally.

My question is what is my problem? and how can I resolve this?

Comment: I don't sure, but is it possible https://stackoverflow.com/q/60492910/1539100 is relative to my error? my error code is different

Comment: Are you sure your cert in the UWP app is still valid? Open it and check dates, maybe you need to generate fresh cert. And self signed certs are not valid for side loaded apps, you need code signing cert if you make packages not for win store.

Comment: Yes I sure, because before this problem, msbuild says expire cert error, that I renew cert and resolve this problem, I say again this project is completely build in my PC without any error on PowerShell. thanks for response

Comment: Please check if your github repos contains the pfx certificate file, in general, it will ignore pfx file when upload the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the PackageCertificateKeyFile and sure the file push to the GitHub. And you should add the password to your pfx file.

```
    /p:PackageCertificateKeyFile=Package_TemporaryKey.pfx /p:PackageCertificatePassword="123"
```

Please replace the `Package_TemporaryKey.pfx` and the password.

If you do not want to push the pfx file to GitHub that you can use [github secrets](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets)

The first is parse the pfx file as base64 string.

The second is set the pfx file base64 string to github secrets.

And then you can use this base64 string before you start build.

```
Decode the Base64 encoded Pfx
- name: Decode the Pfx
  run: |
    $pfx_cert_byte = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String("${{ secrets.Base64_Encoded_Pfx }}")
    $currentDirectory = Get-Location
    $certificatePath = Join-Path -Path $currentDirectory -ChildPath $env:Wap_Project_Directory -AdditionalChildPath $env:SigningCertificate
    [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$certificatePath", $pfx_cert_byte)
```

And you can find my sample code in [github](https://github.com/dotnet-campus/TranslationTool/blob/a640788c6a291cbf259ef73c616712766ac61523/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L1)

Edit

I read your code and found the `DemoApp.UWP_TemporaryKey.pfx` and `Windows_TemporaryKey.pfx` file. Because my Internet speed is very poor, and could you clean your code by `git clean -xdf` and then use commandline to compile in locally? Maybe you should explicitly specify which file to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying, Did I can use your command with msbuild automatically? ( for example write something in csproj or in sln files?) or I have to write command in script file?

Comment: @sorosh_sabz  Please try, I haven't tried it myself

Comment: I remove Windows_TemporaryKey.pfx and all things is correct, thanks :)